# Notification drawer seems full - New notification's get thrown away

Tags: java, android, notifications, push, draw

I'm using Push Notifications in my application and have noticed that if around 50+ notifications arrive the draw stops displaying any new notification that may arrive.

This situation should be rare within my application but its still possible and I'm trying to find out more information about it (since I can't find a mention of a limit anywhere) and the best way to deal with it (so far I'm thinking using SQLlite and storing the overdraw notifications and showing them when the user dismisses a notification).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do not show "50+ notifications". Please show *one* `Notification`, updated perhaps to reflect 50+ events.

This is covered:

- in [the design guidelines](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html) (see "Stack your notifications")
- in [the API guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Updating)
- in [the Android Wear documentation](https://developer.android.com/wear/notifications/stacks.html) (as people with Android Wear devices will get severely pissed at you for flooding their watch or whatever with 50+ notifications)

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question which is really what is the upper limit of notifications the draw can show - I have read all the documentation all ready and have my reasons for not wishing to stack them.

Comment: @jwz: "what is the upper limit of notifications the draw can show" -- that is up to the OS and device/ROM manufacturer. There is no documented limit, and the implemented limits will vary by device model, based upon the OS version and manufacturer changes. "and have my reasons for not wishing to stack them" -- bear in mind that your users will therefore have their reasons for giving you low ratings on the Play Store, if they disagree with your decision. You are not more important than your users. At minimum, give them configuration options to control this unexpected behavior.

Comment: Thank you. I will give it some more serious thought but its actually the users that define how many/what notifications they receive which is why I'm worried, in theory they should only receive notifications but since they can do what they like I would rather have something to deal with this. This app will be the extension of existing product and its users will expect this behaviour as a result, I've been explicitly asked to produce this behaviour.

Comment: Ultimately I think I'll have to compromise in some fashion here. Perhaps let users define a limit after which the notification will stack turn into a single stack or produce another activity in the application that represents the notifications in some fashion.

Comment: @jwv: "Perhaps let users define a limit after which the notification will stack turn into a single stack" -- in theory, that seems reasonable. However, this then rolls back to your original concern. While whatever environment you are testing upon may have a limit of 50, there may be devices that limit it further. I could easily see somebody deciding to limit it to 10. The SDK is expecting an app to have one, or *maybe* a couple, of notifications, and therefore individual apps aren't really concerned about any device limits.

Comment: @jwv: If you go unstacked, even with user control over the stacking limit, it could be that users will be on devices where notifications get dropped before it hits the stacking limit. Off the cuff, and IMHO, the only control that will be reliable will be "stacked" or "unstacked". And for users who choose "unstacked", you warn them at an appropriate time when their use of the app exceeds some threshold of possible simultaneous notifications (e.g., 10), so they understand the risks that they take.

Comment: That's pretty much exactly what I was thinking, going down to around 10 notifications (at least).